# ［Web scrapping］Page navigation using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to web scrap car reviews on the below webpage for personal interests

[www.cardekho.com/user-reviews/maruti-alto-800](http://www.cardekho.com/user-reviews/maruti-alto-800)

I suceeded in scrapping reviews on the first page with the below codes

``` your text``pip install selenium ``` your text`pip install webdriver-manager` your text`import selenium` your text`from selenium import webdriver` your text`from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

`your text`from selenium import webdriver
`your text`from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
`your text`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
`your text`driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

`your text`url = 'https://www.cardekho.com/user-reviews/maruti-alto-800'
`your text`driver.get(url)

`your text`reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".contentspace")

`your text`for i in reviews:
`your text`i_title = i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3 > a")
`your text`i_desc = i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p")
`your text`print(i_title.text, i_desc.text)

But i do not seem to be able to scrap all the other remaining reviews on the next pages
They range from 1 to 16 and they include "next".

1. Could you please help me with scrapping from all the other pages
2. I would like to include star metrics with each review in my dateframe. Any way to scrap them as well?

Thanks in advance

I tried the below codes selecting the main part of "page bar"
But page_bar[0] got me page#6 and more than [0] would give me "list out of range"

`your text`page_bar = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#rf01 > div.app-content > div > div:nth-child(1) > main > div > div.gsc_col-xs-12.gsc_col-sm-12.gsc_col-md-8.gsc_col-lg-9 > div:nth-child(3) > section > div > div.marginTop20 > div > div > div > ul')

```
`your text`for i in page_bar:
    `your text`print(i.text)
```

page_bar[0].click()`

Comment: You know that "scrap" is what you do with a car which no longer works? Extracting information from a web site is to _scrape_ it.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the next pages, you will notice the link containing the page numbers.

Eg Page 2: https://www.cardekho.com/user-reviews/maruti-alto-800/2?subtab=latest

Eg Page 3: https://www.cardekho.com/user-reviews/maruti-alto-800/3?subtab=latest

Therefore, to complete your task you just need to add a for loop going through pages 1-16 by changing the number in the link and you would have scraped all the pages you needed.

For example,

```
for i in range(1, 16):
    CurrentLinkIs = "https://www.cardekho.com/user-reviews/maruti-alto-800/" + str(i) + "?subtab=latest"
    #perform your scraping here
    #.
    #.
    #.
```